# How to remove prompt for ejecting cd on ubuntu 16.04 iso

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, iso-image

I'm trying to create an iso that runs a script and turns off the machine (based off of the instructions listed by Peter Pudlak [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)).

With a few tweaks, everything seems to work on a ubuntu 16.04 iso. However, when I power off the machine, I'm prompted to eject the cd on shutdown. The machine does not power off until I manually hit enter. I'm trying to automate this process and can't manually hit enter when prompted. Is there a way to either

1. Force turning off the machine without hitting this prompt or
2. Customizing the iso further so that it doesn't have this behavior?

[This](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/ubuntu-remove-the-prompt-to-eject-cd/) article explains how to do what I want, but the files that it lists in step 6 are not part of a ubuntu 16.04 desktop iso. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After obtaining the base system for the Ubuntu ISO, edit the file `/etc/rc0.d/S89casper` and make the following modifications:

```
# eject -p -m /cdrom >/dev/null 2>&1

# [ "$prompt" ] || return 0
## Add the following line: 
return 0

# XXX - i18n
# MSG="Please remove the disc and close the tray (if any) then press ENTER: "

# Modify 
/sbin/usplash_write "TIMEOUT 86400"

# To read 
/sbin/usplash_write "TIMEOUT 0"
```

See: https://askubuntu.com/a/87508/214875

Comment: Thanks for checking in. I don't think those files exist on the 16.04 ISO (speculating: because 16.04 changed over to using systemd?). The files that I see in `/etc/rc0.d` look totally different (e.g., K01alsa-utils, K01cups-browsed, etc.). Additionally, looking through the files that are on the 16.04 ISO, I couldn't find anything that looked similar to the snippet that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu 16.04 Live CD, the script that ejects the CD and waits for the keypress seems to be `/sbin/casper-stop`.

It's probably better not to delete the script, but if you comment out the lines `plymouth watch-keystroke > /dev/null` and `read x < /dev/console`, they should prevent the system from waiting for the Enter key.